Error in versioning of analysis services cubes when working in parallel
When handling cube versioning with Analysis Services, I am getting an error in which the other person replaces the XML code in the .DSV object.
When trying to merge Visual Studio asks me what part of the code I want to replace or unify, but since there are so many new dimensions, replacing or unifying code becomes cumbersome and if I start to replace or unify code many times it is replaced or unified where it is not and the diagram starts to throw an error.
